# WPF - How can I make generic binding for DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress-wpf

I've tried to search on the internet for an idea to solve my problem but I didn't get any.

I have these DataTemplates:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UnitGridCell">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Row.Unit.NewValue}" Style="{StaticResource PartStyle}"  />
        <dxe:TextEdit  EditValue="{Binding Row.Unit.OldValue}" Style="{StaticResource PartStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="PreGridCell">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Row.Pre.NewValue}" Style="{StaticResource PartStyle}"  />
        <dxe:TextEdit  EditValue="{Binding Row.Pre.OldValue}" Style="{StaticResource PartStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ExecutionGridCell">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Row.Execution.NewValue}" Style="{StaticResource PartStyle}"  />
        <dxe:TextEdit  EditValue="{Binding Row.Execution.OldValue}" Style="{StaticResource PartStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

for these GridColumns:

```
 <Grid >
    <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridModels}" >
    <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="UnitCol" FieldName="Unit"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource UnitGridCell}"/>
    <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="PreCol" FieldName="Pre"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource PreGridCell}"/>
    <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="ExCCol" FieldName="Execution" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ExecutionGridCell}"/>
```

and the question is : how can I make a generic binding so I can make one DataTemplate for all grid columns?

And thank you in advance !

Comment: Generics wouldn't be a solution for your problem, neither in C# nor XAML. Because you are referencing the source properties via an _individual_ nested property path you require special knowledge about each type. Obviously the operation is not generic as it differs for each case. If your DataTemplate has no DataType specified and the binding path is the same for all data types, then you can use a single DataTemplate for any type that follows the constraint of having identical binding paths. You can ensure this by moving the relevant common properties to a base class.

Comment: In your case you must create a source collection e.g. of type object that contains all the instances that you get when referencing the second level properties Unit, Pre and Execution. In other words you must eliminate the nested paths and bind directly to NewValue and OldValue. Then you can use a single DataTemplate, but only when all binding paths target common properties and the DataTemplate.DataType property is not set..

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot reuse the same template and only replace the binding path in XAML.

A template must be defined as a whole.

You may consider to create the templates *programmtically* using the [XamlReader.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) method but there is no markup (XAML only) solution.

Using `XamlReader.Parse` will let you use a method like `string.Replace` to replace the binding path for each column. You will still have to create a template per column but it will let you define the XAML markup for the template once in a `string` variable or similar.